# ListBox in Visual Studio is throwing up error for trying to take index of one ListBox and trying to find value of one with same index

Tags: visual-studio-2013, listbox

I have two list boxes, named Recipes and Quantity. When attempting to get the value in the index of Quantity with the selected index of Recipes it throws up the error 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'', this is all happening in when the selected index of Recipes changes so this may be the problem.

```
 Private Sub Recipes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Recipes.SelectedIndexChanged
     Dim IndexVal As Integer = Recipes.SelectedIndex
     Dim TextInIndexOfRecipes As String = Recipes.Items(IndexVal).ToString()
     Dim TextInIndexOfQuantity As Integer = Quantity.Items(IndexVal).ToInt()
     MsgBox("Recipe:" + TextInIndexOfRecipes + " Quantity:" +TextInIndexOfQuantity)
```

No idea what the cause of this is, any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `Quantity` using the index value from `Recipes`. Unless these lists/arrays are the same length then you are going to get this error.

The fact that it's complaining about index 0 being invalid would imply that `Quantity` is in fact empty.

Comment: Thanks for that. I stupidly had another listbox named quantity and the listbox I was trying to get the index of was named servings, not quantity. Very happy about your response.